# How does socket.io send binary data within a nested javascript object

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, socket.io-1.0

anybody know the underlying implementation details of how socket.io can send binary data nested within a JS object?

For example, the example on their website on the [socket.io 1.0 announcement](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary) is

```
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  fs.readFile('image.png', function(err, buf){
    // it's possible to embed binary data
    // within arbitrarily-complex objects
    socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf });
  });
});
```

I'm integrating webrtc into my site and no webrtc libraries seem to support this functionality, so I want to roll it myself. Reading through the socket.io 1.0 source was quite dense though, so any higher level overview or pointers on a better way to approach the source are appreciated!

**clarification:** using base64 encoding is **not** an option for me. I've tried it for my specific application and the performance impact of encoding was too large.

Comment: I don't get it, your problem is relative to webRTC or sending binary data through sockets? (and what about this "js object" ?)

Comment: @Ernest I think he means json (javascript object notation).

Comment: The problem is that webRTC datachannels only support binary or text modes. However, I need to send some JSON data along with a blob nested inside. The reason I called it a JS object is because binary blobs are not technically part of the JSON specification... but you can have a javscript object that has a blob as a value! :-)

Comment: @jiang14t Is not an option to send two messages? The first one with the data you want the other peer to know and just after that the binary data? In the official page they say: "Note: real-world applications require a file transfer protocol". For "protocol" I understand more than 1 message.